# assembler compiler on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, tasm

I'm practicing with the basics assembler and I have one question. how do I compile programs on windows 7 64-bit and which site to download the compiler. I might add that we are working in the "tasm" compiler and processor family 8086. I mean simple programs such as addition, subtraction like this:

```
.model tiny
.stack 2
.data
mydata segment
arg1 db 4
arg2 db 2
mydata ends
mycode segment
assume cs:mycode, ds:mydata
begin:
mov ax,seg mydata
mov ds, ax
mov bl, arg2
add bl, arg1
mov dl, bl
add dl, 48
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
naszkod ends
end begin
```

Thanks for help

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tasm&oq=tasm&aqs=chrome..69i57.376j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=tasm+download

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a "Please hunt down the tools  I need" site. If you have a specific question about a problem with the ASM code, please ask it. If your question is "Where do I find tasm or dosbox?", please use Google or Bing. The [help/on-topic] page clearly says that questions asking us to find tools or websites are off-topic here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some (partial) answers that might help you:

- The code you posted is 16-bit assembly for DOS, so an x64 assembler is not going to help you.
- If you are actually looking for a 64-bit capable assembler for the Windows platform, there are several. Among them would be [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) and Microsoft's [MASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx), which (depending on the version) comes with the DDK and/or Visual Studio.
- I don't know if this is of interest to you but there are also some 64-bit compilers which (unlike VC++ x64) allow inline assembly (e.g. Delphi x64).